# How to track types of questions being asked in QnAMaker?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

Is it possible to do an Analytics query that would report how many answers containing a given metadata where hit?
If not how could I report a count of the different categories of QnA pairs?

I couldn’t find the metadata being logged in Analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own [Custom Telemetry Client](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-AppInsights) for retrieving the metadata returned from the QnAMaker API and you can use [Ibex Dashboard](https://github.com/Azure/ibex-dashboard) for Data Visualization.

Comment: Ok, so there's no logging of that information by default then?

Comment: @MartínLaRosa No. Metadata is considered as a customEvent. You need to write a custom telemetry module for that purpose.